# Android - downloading and storing data in Room in background

Tags: android, android-room, persistence, freeze, android-viewmodel

My app relies on downloading data from the web. The data is downloaded and stored in Room, but it can change anytime, so the data must be downloaded on each app start (if the internet connection is available). Additionally the data is presented in an adapter, so in a different place than downloading (MainActivity). The problem is that the app freezes for the downloading, storing and reading process, even if the data didn't change.

I have created the following classes:

Dao:

```java
@Dao
public interface AppDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertHolidayDay(HolidayDay day);

    @Query("DELETE FROM holiday_day")
    void deleteAllHolidayDays();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertHoliday(Holiday holiday);

    @Query("DELETE FROM holiday")
    void deleteAllHolidays();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertFloatingHoliday(FloatingHoliday floatingHoliday);

    @Query("DELETE FROM floating_holiday")
    void deleteAllFloatingHolidays();
}
```

Database:

```java
@Database(entities = {Holiday.class, FloatingHoliday.class, HolidayDay.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract AppDao appDao();
}
```

Repository:

```java
public class AppRepository {
    private final AppDao holidayDao;
    private final MediatorLiveData<List<HolidayDay>> mergedHolidays = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    private List<HolidayDay> fixedHolidaysCache;
    private List<FloatingHoliday> floatingHolidaysCache;

    public AppRepository(final Application application) {
        final AppDatabase database = Room.databaseBuilder(application, AppDatabase.class, "uhc")
                .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        holidayDao = database.appDao();
        loadHolidays();
    }

    @Transaction
    public void updateCalendarData(@NonNull final UnusualCalendar calendar) {
        holidayDao.deleteAllHolidays();
        holidayDao.deleteAllHolidayDays();
        holidayDao.deleteAllFloatingHolidays();
        calendar.getFixed()
                .stream()
                .map(HolidayDay::getHolidays)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .forEach(holidayDao::insertHoliday);
        calendar.getFixed().forEach(holidayDao::insertHolidayDay);
        calendar.getFloating().forEach(holidayDao::insertFloatingHoliday);
    }

    private void loadHolidays() {
        final LiveData<List<HolidayDay>> fixedHolidays = holidayDao.getAllHolidayDays();
        final LiveData<List<FloatingHoliday>> floatingHolidays = holidayDao.getAllFloatingHolidays();

        mergedHolidays.addSource(fixedHolidays, fixed -> {
            fixedHolidaysCache = fixed;
            mergeHolidays();
        });

        mergedHolidays.addSource(floatingHolidays, floating -> {
            floatingHolidaysCache = floating;
            mergeHolidays();
        });
    }

    private void mergeHolidays() {
        // magic here
    }
}
```

SharedViewModel:

```java
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public static final ViewModelInitializer<SharedViewModel> INITIALIZER = new ViewModelInitializer<>(SharedViewModel.class, creationExtras -> {
        final UHCApplication uhcApplication = (UHCApplication) creationExtras.get(ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY);
        assert uhcApplication != null;
        return new SharedViewModel(uhcApplication.getAppRepository());
    });
    private final AppRepository repository;

    public SharedViewModel(final AppRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void updateData(final UnusualCalendar calendar) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> repository.updateCalendarData(calendar));
    }
}
```

Downloading in MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private final List<HolidayDay> holidayDays = new ArrayList<>();
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> internet;
    private volatile boolean downloading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        configureObservers();

        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(internet.getValue()) && !downloading) {
            initiateDownload();
        }

        // Observe the holiday data
        sharedViewModel.getAllHolidayDays().observe(this, days -> {
            if (!days.isEmpty()) {
                holidayDays.addAll(days);
            } else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(internet.getValue())) {
                showNoInternetAlert();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initiateDownload() {
        downloading = true;
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Downloader()) // just a HttpsUrlConnection + gson
                .thenAcceptAsync(data -> {
                    sharedViewModel.updateData(data);
                    downloading = false;
                });
    }

    private void configureObservers() {
        internet = new MutableLiveData<>(Util.isNetworkAvailable(this));
        internet.observe(this, isConnected -> {
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isConnected) && alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing() && !downloading) {
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Downloader.UnusualCalendarDownloader())
                        .thenAccept(sharedViewModel::updateData);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Util.NETWORK_CAPABILITIES.stream()
                .map(new NetworkRequest.Builder()::addTransportType)
                .map(NetworkRequest.Builder::build)
                .forEach(x -> connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(x, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(@NonNull final Network network) {
                        super.onAvailable(network);
                        internet.postValue(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLost(@NonNull final Network network) {
                        super.onLost(network);
                        internet.postValue(false);
                    }
                }));
    }

    private void showNoInternetAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.no_internet);
        alertDialog = alert.show();
    }
}
```

The `CompletableFuture` is imported from `java9.util.concurrent`. I can't rely on `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` as entries can sometimes disappear and I want to get rid of them from the database as well.

My preferable solution is to make the app responsive all the time and allow the data to be updated dynamically as they are stored and read (users can see them updating).

I thought about updating the list in the SharedViewModel, but it didn't resolve the freezing issue.

Comment: I would suggest you to use ```WorkManager``` for fetching data from API and save it to room cache and then Make a ViewModel which will used to fetch those data from room and show it in adapter

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that something is simply blocking the main thread, most likely, it is a database operation. By default, Android won't let you do this, but if you make a request in a separate thread, for example, but tell the main thread to wait for it to complete, it can block the main thread. I would suggest turning on the debugger and looking for the last place where the program worked without freezing.

And your constructor looks very strange.

```
public SharedViewModel(final AppRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }   return repository.getHoliday(id)
```

Comment: sorry, I wrongly pasted the code, fixed. And the program never worked without freezing, this is something I'm struggling with since I added Room

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).